# Find lines with specific characters recursively

Tags: powershell

I am searching for all lines with '.png' and '.jpg' strings in them across multiple folders of TXT files.

Tried:

```
   (Get-ChildItem K:\FILES -Recurse -Include '*.txt') | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_) -match '\.png','\.jpg' | out-file K:\Output.txt
   }
```

but it does not output anything. No error either. I did something similar recently and it was working. I am scratching my head wondering what am I doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing your [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) call *inside the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) script block*,  you're rewriting your output file *in full* for every input file, so that the *last* input file's results - which may be *none* - end up as the sole content of the file.

The immediate fix is to **move the `Out-File` call to its own pipeline segment, so that it receives *all* output**, across all files:

```bash
Get-ChildItem K:\FILES -Recurse -Include '*.txt' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    @(Get-Content $_) -match '\.png', '\.jpg'
  } |
  Out-File K:\Output.txt
```

Note: Technically, adding `-Append` to your `Out-File` call *inside* the `ForEach-Object` could have worked too, but this approach should be *avoided*:

- Every `Out-File` call must open and close the output file, which makes the operation much slower.
- You need to ensure that there is no *preexisting* output file *beforehand* - otherwise you'll end up appending to that file's existing content.

---

However, consider **speeding up your command** with the help of **[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)**:

```bash
Get-ChildItem K:\FILES -Recurse -Include '*.txt' | 
  Select-String -Pattern '\.png', '\.jpg' |
  ForEach-Object Line |
  Out-File K:\Output.txt
```

Note:

- In [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can use the `-Raw` switch with `Select-String`, which directly outputs only the *text* of all matching lines, in which case `ForEach-Object Line` isn't needed.

---

If you want to **prefix each matching line with the source file path**:

```bash
Get-ChildItem K:\FILES -Recurse -Include '*.txt' | 
  Select-String -Pattern '\.png', '\.jpg' |
  ForEach-Object { '{0}: {1}' -f $_.Path, $_.Line } |
  Out-File K:\Output.txt
```

Note: If you pipe `Select-String` output *directly* (without `-Raw` or `ForEach-Object Line`) to `Out-File` (or if you use `>`), you'll get *similar* output (even including a *character position*), but with *limitations*:

- You'll get a blank line at the top and the bottom of the file.
- Long line texts may be *truncated*.

The reason is that `Out-File` and its virtual alias `>` send the *for-display* representations of the input objects to the output file, which aren't meant for *programmatic* processing and can incur truncation of the data based on the line length (number of columns) of the current console window.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, that was it - outfile inside. Thank you. One thing you said intrigued me. I thought the -Raw switch abandons line processing and was not designed to work with, well, lines. Apparently I was wrong. So much to learn :)

Comment: My pleasure, @KolesGit. `-Raw` means different things in different cmdlets (it's not a great parameter name); the meaning you're referring to applies to `Get-Content`. If you're curious about the backstory, see [GitHub issue #7855](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7855).